# How to Upgrade to the new Yahoo weather API?

Tags: c#, xml, weather-api, yahoo-weather-api

For some time now i have been using the Yahoo Weather Api to get current day temperature and forecasts for statistics in a .Net application in C#.
Apparently Yahoo updated their api and  the application fails to get the data.

I am using an xml document like this to get the data

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("http://xml.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=" + WOEID + "&u=c");
    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    ns.AddNamespace("yweather", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");

    XmlNode nod = doc.SelectSingleNode("/rss/channel/link", ns);
    link = nod.InnerText;
    ....more nodes selected....
```

and like this i get the xml nodes and values to store them in the database.

What changes do I have to make so that the application will work with the new the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all we need to change the url that we are asking for the forecast from

```
 doc.Load("http://xml.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=" + WOEID + "&u=c");
```

to

```
      query="select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20%3D%20"+ WOEID 
           + "%20and%20u=%27c%27";
      doc.Load("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q="+query+"&format=xml
                 &env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys");
```

then we need to change the nodes path because the new xml document is slightly different from the old one.

change from

```
XmlNode nod = doc.SelectSingleNode("/rss/channel/link", ns);
```

to

```
XmlNode nod = doc.SelectSingleNode("/query/results/channel/link", ns);
```

and everything should be working fine.